# Regex to only match a multi-line string w/ keyword in its proper place

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a Virtual Instrument file with blocks that may contain any combination of attributes looking like this:

```
POINT=69
    Name="M_Frequency Min" Type=ANALOG
    Units="Hz"
    Archive="AVERAGE" Priority=9999 Latch=0
    HysEnable=0 HysVal=0.00000
    Bit="0"
    Category="Meter"
    IsCustom=1
    Interval=0
    Accumulated=0
    DisplayOrder=1
ENDPOINT
POINT=70
    Name="M_Voltage Phase A-N Max" Type=ANALOG
    Units="Volts"
    Archive="AVERAGE" Priority=9999 Latch=0
    HysEnable=0 HysVal=0.000000
    CritHiEnable=0 CritHiLimit=0.000000
    CritLoEnable=0 CritLoLimit=0.000000
    CautHiEnable=0 CautHiLimit=0.000000
    CautLoEnable=0 CautLoLimit=0.000000
    Desc="Voltage Phase A-N Max"
    RW=READ
    Register="9000"
    RegType="H"
    DataType="F"
    Accumulated=0
    DisplayOrder=1
ENDPOINT
```

Say, I'd like to only match the second block (and not the first) using something like `POINT=[0-9]*(?s)(.*?)(?!ENDPOINT)(\sMax)(.*?)ENDPOINT`

My thinking here being that if I set my dot-star to also match line breaks but then tell it to only match lazy that it would stop if it looked forward and saw something that disqualified the match. Obviously, I'm not getting something here.

This, of course, doesn't work and instead finds the entire text to match. I've also tried using a negative character set, but also no dice. *What I'm trying to match is a POINT to ENDPOINT block only if it has my desired string " Max" and I would like to disqualify a block that terminates with "ENDPOINT" before having found " Max".*

EDIT1: You can assume that there will be more blocks like this one before and after the snippet shown. I'm specifically trying to get the block that has my target string in it (so I can replace it with another, or delete). Other blocks may or may not have the target string in them, but if they do, I'd like to match each block each separately, not as a single match.

Comment: Do you mean *last block* by *second block*? or they can be different blocks?

Comment: In this case the last and 2nd are the same, but you can assume that there will be more blocks like it before and after. I'll make an edit to specify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [the following regex](https://regex101.com/r/fnQ7x6/3):

```
^\s*POINT=\d+\s*$  # A line matching to the word POINT,
                   # followed by the character '=' and one
                   # or more decimal digits surrounded by
                   # whitespace characters.
(?:\r?\n)+   # A zero or one character '\r' before the
             # character '\n'. This sequence may be
             # repeated one or more times.
  (?:                     # Zero or more lines that is not
    ^(?!                  # matched with the ENDPOINT word
      \s*(?:POINT=\d+|    # or the word POINT followed by
            ENDPOINT)\s*$ # the character '=' and zero or
    ).*$                  # more decimal digits surrounded
    (?:\r?\n)+            # by whitespace characters.
  )*
                  # A line that starts with one or more
                  # characters that are not equal to the
  ^[^=]+=.*Max.*$ # '=' character, followed by the '='
                  # character, and finally the word Max
                  # followed by zero or more characters.
  (?:\r?\n)+
  (?:
    ^(?!
      \s*(?:POINT=\d+|ENDPOINT)\s*$
    ).*$
    (?:\r?\n)+
  )*
^\s*ENDPOINT\s*$ # A line matching to the word ENDPOINT,
                 # surrounded by whitespace characters.
```

Comment: I checked this against my file and it works! It only grabs the sections with the target string in them. I'm still parsing it to figure out why exactly it works but one place I can already see that I was tripped up was that even when you lazy select .* in single-line mode with a bit of text you expect it to stop at, you'll still grab more than you want in some cases. Thank you good sir!

Comment: @CarlCampbell, comments have been added.